# Div does not respect width and height when triggered on click

Tags: javascript, html

The following snippet is supposed to replace the static image with the window loaded by the Javascript function, when the user clicks the image. The problem is that the Javascript block that is loaded does not respect the width and height if its `div` element, it gets squished to the left.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
 <div style="text-align: center;">


<!-- Your image -->
<img id="myImage" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ucc23/test/main/berkeley29.webp" alt="Clickable Image" style="width:355px;height:250px; cursor: pointer;">


<!-- Div to contain Aladin Lite viewer -->
<div id="aladin-lite-div" style="width:355;height:250"></div>

<!-- Aladin Lite script (will be loaded after the image is clicked) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Function to load Aladin Lite after image click and hide the image
function loadAladinLiteAndHideImage() {
    // Dynamically load the Aladin Lite script
    let aladinScript = document.createElement('script');
    aladinScript.src = "https://aladin.cds.unistra.fr/AladinLite/api/v3/latest/aladin.js";
    aladinScript.charset = "utf-8";
    aladinScript.onload = function () {
        A.init.then(() => {
            let aladin = A.aladin('#aladin-lite-div', {survey:"P/DSS2/color", fov:0.1, target: "103.269 16.929"});
            // Remove the image
            document.getElementById('myImage').remove();
            // Hide the image
            //document.getElementById('myImage').style.visibility = "hidden";
                      // Show the Aladin Lite viewer
            document.getElementById('aladin-lite-div').style.display = 'block';
});
     };
    document.head.appendChild(aladinScript);
}
// Event listener for image click
document.getElementById('myImage').addEventListener('click', loadAladinLiteAndHideImage);
</script>

</div>
<!-- Left block -->

<table style="text-align: center; width:355px;height:250px;">
  <!-- Row 1 (title) -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><h3>Table title</h3></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <tr>
    <th><a>C1</a></th>
    <th><a>C2</a></th>
    <th><a>C3</a></th>
    <th><a>C4</a></th>
    <th><a>C5</a></th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 3 -->
  <tr>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>0.52</td>
    <td>9.7</td>
    <td>534</td>
    <td>3.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Gabriel, I am not sure where the element whose id is ```myimage``` that is called from script : ```// Event listener for image click
document.getElementById('myImage').addEventListener('click', loadAladinLiteAndHideImage);```

Comment: In addition, I am not sure putting script inside <body> that contains html , is qualified. Why don't you just that script outside <body> part?